# POWER BIOn-Prem Data Gateway "Reachable," but data sets failing to refresh

Tags: powerbi, gateway

My on-prem (personal) data gateway suddenly stopped working for data sets uploaded to a shared workspace in Power BI online. It had been working with no issues up until a few days ago. I tried to reinstall the gateway, and still getting errors. Here's the message I'm getting:

```
Data source error: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_SignatureNotMatchCredentialError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_SignatureNotMatchCredentialError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"InvalidCredentialFormat - Signature does not match"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2146233033"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: Agency Care Management + Benefits + Aid Dashboard - clients with HH members impa. Cluster URI: WABI-US-EAST-A-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net Activity ID: 46595fea-b3bc-4c8d-8df3-9ec459ce53b7 Request ID: 8cca2569-5146-d233-3cb9-5196807ab960 Time: 2023-03-22 12:58:35Z
```

What should I try next?

Thanks,

Noah

Comment: Delete and recreate the gateway data connections in the Power BI Service.

Comment: Uninstalled gateway from computer, deleted in Power BI online, installed through link in Power BI online, connected data set to new gateway, and same error